# Can't Seem to get the ionic cordova build android command to work?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

Every time I run the command:

`ionic cordova build android`

I receive this error:

````
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 12.0.2
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.```
````

Comment: Do you have android sdk installed? If not, I recommend you install android studio rather than just the sdk

Comment: I have android studio installed